# Sequently validate two different constraints with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

I'm using Symfony 4.4 and I have form like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MainForm extends AbstractType
{
    public const GROUP_CREATE = 'create';
    public const GROUP_UPDATE = 'update';

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('zone', TargetingZoneForm::class, [
                'targeting_validation_groups' => [
                    MainForm::GROUP_CREATE,
                    MainForm::GROUP_UPDATE,
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }
}

class TargetingZoneForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('is_excluded', CheckboxType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type([
                        'type' => 'bool',
                        'groups' => $options['targeting_validation_groups'],
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('list', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => IntegerType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range([
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 2147483647,
                            'groups' => $options['targeting_validation_groups'],
                        ]),
                    ],
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Count([
                        'max' => \App\Model\Zone::ZONE_LIMITATIONS_MAX,
                        'maxMessage' => 'You can use up to {{ limit }} zones',
                        'groups' => $options['targeting_validation_groups'],
                    ]),
                    new \App\Constraints\Zone([
                        'groups' => $options['targeting_validation_groups'],
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setRequired(['targeting_validation_groups']);
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('targeting_validation_groups', 'array');
    }
}
```

My payload is like this:

```
{
  "zone": {
    "list": [
      "1",
      "26606653111701",
      "3"
    ],
    "is_excluded": false
  }
}
```

I want to validate all of the elements of the collection for `Range` constraint, and only if it is valid - fire my custom `\App\Constraints\Zone` constraint after if (because inside I will have all valid IDs and send a single DB query). I failed to do so with `GroupSequence`.

I can't use `Sequentially` because I'm using Symfony 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the [All Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/constraints/All.html). You can apply it on arrays with same values, like your array of integers in the `list` property of your form. You can then pass any constraints you need, and they will be applied to each element of the array.

Judging by the documentation, it should be available in Symfony 4.4.